# How can i respond with custom error in Akka gRPC

Tags: akka, grpc, akka-http, grpc-java, akka-grpc

How does one send an error while using Akka-gRPC. I'm aware of `responseObserver.Error` when using native gRPC interfaces but can't find the best way to do it in Akka-gRPC.

I've tried doing this, however i'm not certain if this is a good approach and besides it doesn't provide benefits of using the google. advance error model

```
override fun createUser(req: CreateUserRequest?): CompletionStage<User>{
    requireNotNull(req)

    val validations = validator.validate(req.user)

    if (validations.isNotEmpty()) return CompletableFuture.failedStage(GrpcServiceException())

    val user = User.newBuilder().build()
    return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(user)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GrpcServiceException` for this: you can either fail the `CompletionStage` with it, or throw it from the `createUser` body.

Comment: this should really be documented better - https://github.com/akka/akka-grpc/issues/701